# Including a variable file on PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

Im struggling with the basics here and any help is appreciated.

I have an index.php in the main website folder:

> www.site.com/index.php

I have a sub folder here with a file I want to include:

> www.site.com/book/application/language/english/translations_lang.php

When trying to include the file in my index.php the website fails to load

I have tried this:

```
<? php include '/book/application/language/english/translations_lang.php'; ?>
```

When the above failed I also removed the slash at the start, I also tried moving the translations file to the same sirectory as the index file but the site fails to load every time.

The translations file has the following:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
// English
$lang['company_name'] = 'Big Company';
```

I think i get an idea that its the BASEPATH thats stopping this from being read and causing the failure of the site.

Help

Comment: "When the above failed"  In what way did if fail?  What _did_ happen?

Comment: First does `index.php` contain `define('BASEPATH', 'something')`?  Second remove the first `/` from `/book`

Comment: The error is a HTTP 500 (using Chrome). The index file has no define(base) etc in it

Comment: Using `/` at the beginning of the path tells PHP to start looking for the file from the system root, not the site root. You need to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or BASEPATH to traverse the actual file.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: If you are getting a 500 status, then you need to check your error logs for the actual error message.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me towards the logs. This is the error: 13-Nov-2019 18:31:32 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'include' (T_INCLUDE)

Comment: Not sure if this is throwing the error, but `<? php` should not have a space in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: I took the space out of the ? PHP - New error of: No direct script access allowed

Comment: So now you just need to define the constant (in index.php) before checking for it (in translations_lang.php)

Comment: This is where Iim getting a bit lost and confused. Define it where exactly

Comment: It's a codeigniter constant, so make sure that the file that you're using to include `translations_lang.php` is also using the Codeigniter framework

Comment: I think you mix up things here, to take advantage of Codeigniters language class: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html

Comment: In the constants.php I have just added this: define('PRIV_INDEX', 'index'); But theres surely something else I need to do for index.php to pick up on this

Comment: Any further advice? Ive checked the config.php and it holds a defined('BASEPATH') in it. Not sure what I need to do here

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
<?php include dirname(__FILE__) . '/book/application/language/english/translations_lang.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. My file is outside of code igniter. Is it still possible to do?

Comment: @tryer  I'm confused.  You tagged this question with _3_ codeigniter tags.  But now you are saying that this code is _not_ using codeigniter?

Comment: @tryer, translations_lang.php is a PHP file to define the array variables. So if you include it, you can use the data in this file anywhere. please include this code block on your index.php define('BASEPATH', dirname(__FILE__));